# How to hide the div structure thing next to the editor tabs

Tags: intellij-idea

There's a colored bar at the top of the Intellij IDEA editor, which shows the div structure. Does anyone know how to hide that? Because everytime I move the cursor to the editor tabs, I cross over the bar which makes the editor blink. (Maybe a better way is to keep the bar, but turn off the blinking when the cursor moves across the bar. Is it possible to do that?)

[image: By "bar" I mean the "html-dody-div..." thing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by unchecking *Show HTML breadcrumbs* in *Settings/Editor/General/Appearance*.